# How to seed Devise users efficiently?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, devise

I'm trying to seed about 100,000 users using rake db:seed in my Rails 3 project and it is really slow!

Here's the code sample:

```
# ...
User.create!(
  :display_name => "#{title} #{name} #{surname}",
  :email => "#{name}.#{surname}_#{num}@localtinkers.com",
  :password => '12341234'
)
```

It works, but it is **really slow** because for each user:

1. Devise issues a SELECT statement to find out if the email is already taken.
2. A separate INSERT statement is issued.

For other objects I use "*ar-extensions*" and "*activerecord-import*" gems as follows:

```
tags.each do |tag|
  all_tags << Tag.new(:name => tag)
end

Tag.import(all_tags, :validate => false, :ignore => true)
```

The above creates just one INSERT statement for all the tags and it works **really fast**, just like MySql database restore from the SQL dump.

But for users I cannot do this because I need Devise to generate encrypted password, salt, etc for each user. Is there a way to generate them on the SQL side or are there other efficient ways of seeding users?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
u = User.new(
  :display_name => "#{title} #{name} #{surname}",
  :email => "#{name}.#{surname}_#{num}@localtinkers.com",
  :password => '12341234'
)
u.save!(:validate => false)
```

This *should* create and save the record without executing the validations, and therefore without checking for e-mail address uniqueness. Obviously the downside of this is that you're not being protected by any other validations on the user too, so make sure you check your data first!

Comment: This gets rid of bullet 1: "select" statement for each new user, and it works a little faster, but the slowest thing is the "insert" looks like. The data in seeds is for testing, so it is OK without validations.

It would be nice if I could do one "insert" for 10,000 users...

Thanks for the tip though - it helps.

Comment: Sorry, gotcha - didn't spot the bulk import. Just a thought: Could you somehow manually trigger devise's before_save hooks, assuming that's how it works?

Comment: That's a great idea actually! I'm pretty sure I could, even if some of those methods are private - I could still call them, since Ruby is an awesome programming language. And then I'll put together an array of raw data and just issue a bulk insert statement... Thank you, I'm marking your answer as correct. :)

Comment: Hrm, just had a quick look at this, and it doesn't look like this is how Devise works. It looks to me like the salt etc is generated in DatabaseAuthenticatable's password= method, so I can't quite see why you couldn't just do User.new (rather than create), and then pass to activerecord-import?

Comment: P.S. Just spotted a stupid error in my code - should've been User.new, not User.create!. Have now fixed.

Comment: Didn't have time to look into is, but it sounds like it would populate all the password-related fields if I do User.new(...), if it is so - then my question is resolved 200%! Thank you :)

Comment: Yup, I saw that mistake, but I got what you mean in your answer anyways :)

Comment: The accepted answer here really is the answer (although its in the comments). It looks like the accepted answer should be updated to reflect using User#new with activerecord-import was the solution, or perhaps a new answer should be accepted altogether.

Comment: What slows it down is the password encryption thing